# how to apply sql binding in Python and Postgresql using "ilike"

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, binding

I'm trying to figure out how to apply sql binding in Python and Postgresql using `ilike`.
I tried any of the below but it didn't work.

```
title_value = "The"
stmt = "select id from titles where title ilike ('%%%%s%%');"
# or
stmt = "select id from titles where title ilike '%%' || '%%s' || '%%';"
# or
stmt = "select id from titles where title ilike '%%%%s%%';"

cur.execute(stmt, title_value)
```

Also, tried name binding instead of `%`s, but still didn't work.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do here, especially with that `%%s`. You want the like argument to be `%The%`, right? But it looks like you're trying to build either `%%The%` or `%%s%`, and unless the former has some postgres-specific meaning that I don't know, it seems extra-wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that parameter substitution doesn't happen inside quotes, so `'%%' || '%%s' || '%%'` just means literally the strings `'%%'`, `'%%s'`, etc.

The most general way around this is to compose strings in Python rather than in SQL, and only pass the composed string as a parameter. So, instead of this:

```
cur.execute('select * from table where title ilike "%%spam%seggs%%"', 
            [conjunction])
```

… you do this:

```
cur.execute('select * from table where title ilike %s', 
            ['%spam{}eggs%'.format(conjunction)])
```

This doesn't open any SQL injection risks (no matter what's in `conjunction`, postgresql is still going to bind it as a parameter, meaning it can't affect anything but the `ilike` clause). And it's easier to write and read, too, because you can use `str.format` instead of `%`-formatting, no need to escape the `%` characters.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't very clear with the requirement but thankfully you got the point. Thanks for your brilliant solution. It perfectly worked. ^_^